# Delphi: Define a static list with type of SQL servers

Tags: list, delphi, types

I'm working to a program that use different type of SQL database servers.
Inside this program I play a lot with this items.

This is how I define the static list now:

```
type 
  TServerType = (stNone, stMsSQL, stMySQL, stSQLite);
```

Now, I would like to associate to this static list the short name and the long name of the server like this:

```
stNone    | (null) | (null)
stMsSQL   | mssql  | Microsoft SQL
stMySQL   | mysql  | MySQL
stSQLLite | sqlite | SQLite
```

Is it possible to do this directly by using this `type`? (can be done without `var` or `const` and `array`)

Or how do you recommend the best to define this associated list?

Comment: I always use conversion functions for this purpose, such as `ServerTypeToStr`, `StrToServerType`, or whatever you may need.

Comment: The answer to this question would be no, use records and declare an array...

Comment: @whosrdaddy can you add a small example please

Comment: What is your problem? Define a record or a const array of that record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A static array will work for that:

```
type 
  TServerType = (stNone, stMsSQL, stMySQL, stSQLite);

  TServerNames = record
    ShortName: String;
    LongName: String;
  end;

const
  ServerNames: array[TServerType] of TServerNames = (
    (ShortName: ''; LongName: ''),
    (ShortName: 'mssql'; LongName: 'Microsoft SQL'),
    (ShortName: 'mysql'; LongName: 'MySQL'),
    (ShortName: 'sqlite'; LongName: 'SQLite')
  );
```

```
var
  ServerType: TServerType;
  ShortName: String;
  LongName: String; 
begin
  ServerType := ...;
  ShortName := ServerNames[ServerType].ShortName;
  LongName := ServerNames[ServerType].LongName;
  ...
end;
```